# How to get this Django REST query to display all fields, including fields from related one-to-one table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

This is my Django `models.py` with 2 tables having a one-to-one table relationship. UserComputedInfo model has a one-to-one relationship with CustomUser model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    post_code = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class UserComputedInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    copy_input = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.copy_input
```

I am trying to create a REST API to display all the fields in the 2 tables. I am using Django REST framework.

This is my `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "post_code")
        model = CustomUser
```

This is my `views.py`

```
from rest_framework import generics

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer


class PostCodeAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```

The API will display all the fields in `CustomUser` table. However, I want to display all the fields in the related one-to-one `UserComputedInfo` table as well.

I am using Django v4, python v3.9, Django REST framework on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. It has been tested to work successfully.

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "post_code", "usercomputedinfo")
        model = CustomUser
        depth = 1  # display all the fields in related 1-to-1 table
```

In https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer, it is stated that `the ModelSerializer class provides a shortcut that lets you automatically create a Serializer class with fields that correspond to the Model fields.`

The field `usercomputedinfo` corresponds to the one-to-one table `UserComputedInfo`. Take special note that the naming of the field follows a convention used by ModelSerializer. In this case, it has to be all lowercase. If you use `UserComputedInfo` as the field, it won't work. I cannot find the documentation on the field naming convention used by ModelSerializer. `depth = 1` is needed to generate nested representations.

Instead of displaying all the fields, sometimes we want to specify specific fields. This is the code for doing it.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import CustomUser, UserComputedInfo


class UserComputedInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserComputedInfo
        fields = ("copy_input")


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usercomputedinfo = UserComputedInfoSerializer()

    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "postal_code", "usercomputedinfo")
        model = CustomUser
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `UserComputedInfoSerializer` in `CustomUserSerializer` like this

```
# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import CustomUser, UserComputedInfo

class UserComputedInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserComputedInfo
        fields = "__all__"

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    UserComputedInfo = UserComputedInfoSerializer(source="usercomputedinfo")
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "post_code", "usercomputedinfo")
        model = CustomUser
```

if you want it only `read_only` so `UserComputedInfoSerializer(read_only=True)` else should handle the operations manually for `UserComputedInfoSerializer` too.

Comment: Your code is almost correct. You have to use `"usercomputedinfo"` in `fields`.